# HttpClient's Credential dialog UI

Tags: c++, uwp

Acccording to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter), the [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient) should automatically show a dialog to prompt for credential upon necessary.

```
auto request = ref new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod::Post, ref new Uri(url));
auto response = create_task(m_httpClient->SendRequestAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption::ResponseContentRead)).get();
```

However, it seems to me that this only works if the above code is put inside a WinRT DLL project: putting the above code in the main app project will not show any UI (and the request fails with Unauthorized code, of course). Is there a secret reason as to why this is the case? (I am targetting 14393 but I am running on the latest Windows 10.)

[image: Automated Authentication Dialog]

Comment: From the document, I did not see it talks about show a dialog. What is the UI that you want to show?

Comment: @Scavenger Please see the `AllowUI` property of [HttpBaseProtocolFilter class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter#AllowUI). I edit the question with screenshot of the sample dialog when attempted to send a Http request that requires authentication using `HttpClient`.